# Aero peek is turned permanently on.How to turn it off?

Tags: windows-7

I Try to turn aero peek off but
1)Unchecking in Taskbar Properties dostn work
2)Control Panel ->Visual Effect unchecking  dosn't work.

I have win 7 is there semething i can do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Registry Method**

1: Open RegEdit and go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM

[image]

2:In Right Side Pane Double Click on "Enable Aero Peek" as in above image and type Value As 0

[image]

3: Reboot

**Easy Method**
1: Right-click on Computer icon on Desktop and select Properties (or press WIN + Pause/Break keys). Now click on Advanced system settings link in left side pane (You can open it directly by giving sysdm.cpl command in RUN or start menu search box).

[image]

2: Now click on Settings button in Performance section:

[image]

3: Now uncheck "Enable Aero Peek" option.

[image]

4: Click on Apply button and it'll disable "Aero Peek" feature in Windows 7.

Comment: Its turned on even with Enable Aero peek unchecked

Comment: Did you log out and log back in?

Comment: Adding alternate registry method above... If that doesn't work I'm tapped out. Between the two methods you listed and these two I know no other way.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question may actually be about Aero Shake not Aero Peek.

Aero Shake is shaking a window to display the desktop. Aero Peek is placing the mouse over the rectangle at the right of the taskbar to display desktop.

To turn off Aero Shake enable the following setting in the Local Group Policy Editor "gpedit.msc".

User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Desktop\Turn off Aero Shake window minimizing mouse gesture

Hope this helps.

Comment: The Aero Shake is a different thing from Peek. I have shake disabled but prefer to have peek (windows+comma) enabled. Sometimes I want to see my desktop wallpaper which is normally obscured by windows (because I sometimes put “this is our production environment” as my wallpaper ;-) ;-) ).