# Turn off TaskBar Thumbnails on Windows 7 - Classic Theme

Tags: windows-7, themes, thumbnails, preview, regedit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable windows 7 taskbar thumbnails preview?](https://superuser.com/questions/202843/how-to-disable-windows-7-taskbar-thumbnails-preview)
>   [Aero peek is turned permanently on.How to turn it off?](https://superuser.com/questions/233262/aero-peek-is-turned-permanently-on-how-to-turn-it-off)

Is there a way to get rid of the annoying thumbnail previews on Windows 7's taskbar? I'm using the Classic theme btw.

Comment: I'm not using the Aero theme.

Comment: I'm confused. Could you provide a screenshot of the thumbnails you're talking about?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/202843/how-to-disable-windows-7-taskbar-thumbnails-preview See saytha comment. I just tested, and with an aero theme the thumbs are back, in classic and basic they are not.

Comment: The answer did not help me. As mentioned I am using the Classic Theme, not Aero..

Comment: http://oi41.tinypic.com/25ouxih.jpg

Comment: @polyglot i see now you want to get rid of the text preview, do try that taskbar tweaker for that.